# TextBlock Text being truncated after rotating 90 degrees

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml

I have a TextBlock that I want to display vertically in a user control that is 30px wide. The TextBlock control has been rotated 90° using a RenderTransform.

The rotation seems to occur fine when I combine it with a 30px translation but the actual content of the TextBlock is truncated at what appears to be 30px.

It seems like the Text is being rendered at the 30px width of the parent and then transformed.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Xyz.Controls.FooControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="30">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid Name="barGrid" Background="#BFFFFFFF">
            <Ellipse Width="30" Height="30" Fill="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            <TextBlock Name="barText" Text="88.8°" 
                       Width="50" 
                       Height="30" 
                       Foreground="#FF3535C4">
                <TextBlock.RenderTransform> 
                    <CompositeTransform Rotation="90" TranslateX="30"/> 
                </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
            </TextBlock>
        </Grid>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

In this screenshot from Visual Studio the expected text is only showing 29px.
[image: Xaml TextBlock content truncated at parent width]

The same issue appears in Expression Blend and the Emulator.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure but it could be that the height of a rotated text is the height from that orientation of the screen so 30px would truncate it. Not sure how to fix it, just a possible cause.

Comment: Changing the d:DesignWidth directly changes the amount of text that can be seen vertically. E.g. Increasing the design width increases the amount of text that appears and vice versa with decreasing the width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured out one way to get the intended layout but it seems like a bit of a hack.

By setting a negative left margin on the TextBlock (-20px) equal to the difference of the TextBox width (50px) and the parents width (30px) the full text is displayed vertically.

E.g.

```
<TextBlock Name="barText" Text="88.8°" 
                   Width="50" 
                   Height="30" 
                   Foreground="#FF3535C4"
                   Margin="0,0,-20,0">
            <TextBlock.RenderTransform> 
                <CompositeTransform Rotation="90" TranslateX="30"/> 
            </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
        </TextBlock>
```

Comment: This does seem to work for my issue but if someone has a better answer I'll move the accept over.

Answer (score 0):

Use a LayoutTransform instead.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).